# Basic stored procedure - why isn't this working?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

New to SPs in Snowflake. I cannot work out why this doesn't work??

Error message is: JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in LOAD_CUSTOMERS at 'var sql = '' position 10

I'd really appreciate someone pointing out what is wrong here to get me going!

'''

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA stage;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE stage.load_customers
(FIRST_NAME VARCHAR);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE stage.load_customers(VAR_SCHEMA VARCHAR, VAR_TABLE VARCHAR)
returns string 
language javascript
as
$$
var sql = '
    INSERT OVERWRITE INTO AM_TEST.';
    
    sql += VAR_SCHEMA;
    sql += '.';
    sql += VAR_TABLE;
    sql += '
 
    SELECT C_FIRST_NAME FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.CUSTOMER LIMIT 100;

try {
    snowflake.execute (
        {sqlText: sql}
        );
    return "Succeeded."; //Return a success
    }
catch (err) {
    return "Failed: " + err; //Return error
}
$$;

call stage.load_customers('stage', 'load_customers');
```

Comment: Looks to me like maybe you just forget a single quote at the end of that last `sql += '` line:   `sql += '
 
    SELECT C_FIRST_NAME FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.CUSTOMER LIMIT 100;';`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Why oh why do we have to use javascript when EVERYTHING else in Snowflake is so EASY!

Comment: You can make it easier on yourself in this instance by using backticks to open and close your strings. You can then use ${variableName} inside the backtick-terminated strings to replace with their values. This syntax support multi-line and multi-variable replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Using backtick (`) will make your sp creation easier and more readable.

The following one is working as expected :

```
CREATE DATABASE AM_TEST;

CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA stage;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE stage.load_customers
(FIRST_NAME VARCHAR);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE stage.load_customers(VAR_SCHEMA VARCHAR, VAR_TABLE VARCHAR)
returns string 
language javascript
as
$$
var sql = `INSERT OVERWRITE INTO AM_TEST.` + VAR_SCHEMA + `.` + VAR_TABLE 
+ ` SELECT C_FIRST_NAME FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.CUSTOMER LIMIT 100;`;

try {
    snowflake.execute (
        {sqlText: sql}
        );
    return "Succeeded."; //Return a success
    }
catch (err) {
    return "Failed: " + err; //Return error
}
$$;

call stage.load_customers('stage', 'load_customers');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your return("success") statement as return(sql) and execute the sql statement separately to validate the syntax and access issue.

Also the quote started before select statement is missing it end?